# Force git rebase to accept my version after an initial merge conflict

Tags: git, merge

Here is a git rebase/merge/continue scenario for which a more expedient approach is requested:

> Given: a file that has changes in both the present branch and the
>   branch being rebased onto.
>
> Already performed: a manual merge of the files.
>
> Complication: the following command seems to be required multiple
>   times: it finds only a small portion of the "required" (according to
>   git) changes to be merged at one shot:

```
    git rebase --continue
```

> Desired outcome: have Git simply "accept" the file that I have in the
>   existing branch.
>
> What has been tried:  after the initial `rebase` the original version
>   of the file was copied on top of the merge conflicted version.
>
> What happened:  after `git rebase --continue` the file is still
>   conflicted - but with a different set of merge conflicts.  This
>   process is repeated now a few times and not done yet.

Can we "jump to the chase" and just accept the file I updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you have multiple conflicts is that you're rebasing multiple commits, with several (all?) of them consisting conflicting changes to the file. You can't skip these conflict resolution steps since you're creating multiple new commits and each requires a specific version of the file, in a resolved state.

You can either continue like before, or you can choose to squash your commits and by that avoid the need to generate multiple commits and only merge once.

Comment: Thx for explaining why this happens. I just hit `git add *` and `git rebase --continue` a few times **ignoring for the time being that the file were a "mess"**.  And then after the last iteration copied over the whole file.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `git rerere`

https://git-scm.com/2010/03/08/rerere.html

Here's the gist (taken from that article):

> The name stands for "reuse recorded resolution" and as the name implies, it allows you to ask Git to remember how you've resolved a hunk conflict so that the next time it sees the same conflict, Git can automatically resolve it for you.

Comment: forgot about that - thanks!  Oh I already had it:  `git config --global rerere.enabled` returns  `true`